# non-separable metric space and measurablility of its elements

Tags: metric-spaces, skorohod-space

I'm studying Skorokhod space, which consists of cadlag functions, and I encountered the following sentence:

> If a metric space
>   $(\mathbb{S}, \mathcal{S}, d)$ is not separable, then functions that map a probability space (Ω,F, P)
>   to $(\mathbb{S}, \mathcal{S}, d)$ often fail to be measurable.

Here, we can substitute $\mathbb{S}$ with $\mathbb{D}$(Skorokhod space) and $d$ with an uniform metric.

However, I don't have any idea how separability affects measurability.

Can anyone give help?